# Resource sharing in multi threaded application

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am trying to initiating multiple threads into one thread.

```
public class TestForm
{
      int samleLoopCounter = 3;
      public TestForm()
      {
            Thread CreateProcessInfoThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessOrders));
            CreateProcessInfoThread.Start();
      }

      void ProcessOrders()
      {
            for (int orderCounter = 0; orderCounter < samleLoopCounter; orderCounter++)
            {
                  EntryPoint obj = new EntryPoint();
                  Thread process = new Thread(obj.Start);
                  process.Start();
            }
      }
}

public class EntryPoint
{
     // No of variable and properties declared here
     ....
     ....

     public void Start()
     {
          // No of Private methods has been calling inside
          ....
          ....
     }
}
```

I have created new instance of `EntryPoint` class every time into loop of `ProcessOrders()` method and start processing thread, but I'm still getting error inside the `Start()` method of `EntryPoint` class at many location related to resource in use Or I'm getting error related to null reference, may be because another thread has already disposed it.

> So the main question is, Does all `process` threads are accessing same variable and memory of
>   `EntryPoint` class, even though I have created new instance of
>   `EntryPoint` class? I'm quite confuse with these.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: If the error is in the `Start` method, then show us the code in the `Start` method that is throwing the errror

Comment: Without more and better info, this is just a null-reference question.